# using class templates without passing template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

```
// p1: some value
// nt: native type
template<int p1, typename nt>
struct A {};

// pt: pointer to type i.e. int*
// tA: a specialization of A
template<typename pt, typename tA>
struct B1 {};

// pt: pointer to type i.e. int*
// tA: a specialization of A
template<typename pt, typename tA>
struct B2 {};

// tB: specialization of B?
// tA: specialization of A
template<typename tB, typename tA>
struct C {};

// now i want to create a C partial specialization where:
//  A<some_value, native_type>
//  B?<char*, A<some_value, native_type> >

template< template<typename, typename> class B, int p1, typename nt >
struct C< B<char*, A<p1, nt> >, A<p1, nt> > {};

int main()
{
    C< B1, A<10, int> > c;
}
```

When compiling the above code with clang it gives the error:

```
error: use of class template B1 requires template arguments
   C< B1, A<10, int> > c;
      ^~
```

I understand the error and to fix it `B1` should be `B1<char*, A<10, int> >`. Should the compiler deduct the value of these parameters from the most matched specialization?

Comment: What compiler is this? Some have trouble with template template-parameters.

Comment: `C` requires two types. So it makes no sense to say `C<B1, ...`, since `B1` is not a type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should the compiler deduct the value of these parameters from the most matched specialization?

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if I do, then the answer is "No". The compiler has no idea how to deduce a fully instantiated type (a specialization of `B1`, in this case) from the bare name of a class template (`B1`, in this case). You have to specify template arguments for `B1`.

Keep in mind that specializations of a primary template are selected after you have provided the necessary arguments for the primary template. In this case, your primary template accepts two *type* parameters, and you have to provide two type arguments.

The fact that you are using a template template parameter `B` in your template specialization in order to match those type parameters which are instances of `B` does not change the fact that the parameters of your primary template are two (fully instantiated) *types*.

Comment: Even for a template template-parameter? That seems odd.

Comment: @StoryTeller: The primary template accepts two type parameters. The template template parameter is only used in the specialization of the primary template to describe the first of those type parameters.

Comment: Ah! Now I see it. Missed it being a specialization. +1

Comment: @AndyProwl: is there any way to change the design of `C` to make passing of 'B1' deductible by the compiler?

Comment: @Muhammadalaa: I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve here, and how you expect the compiler to deduce one of the infinite valid instantiations of `B1`. Could you be more specific? (or perhaps ask a whole new question)